Display field content from a list in a task list
I have a SharePoint with a list, users add new item with a lot of fields who started a workflow with tasks.
I would like to display in the task the customer name from the item list associated but I don't find how to do this with SharePoint designer, the customer name field in the task list stays empty.
Can you help me?
